# Follow-up: Timer utilizing std::future

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, timer

The previous code (as displayed in [Timer utilizing std::future](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46807/timer-utilizing-stdfuture)) is now:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// PeriodicFunction
// =============================================================================

namespace Detail {

/// A functor to invoke a function periodically.
template <typename Value, typename Derived>
class PeriodicFunction
{
    // Types
    // =====

    public:
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds period_type;
    typedef Value value_type;

    protected:
    typedef std::function<Value ()> function_type;
    typedef std::future<Value> future_type;

    // Construction
    // ============

    protected:
    /// Initialize with a function where the arguments are bounded to that function.
    /// \SEE std::bind
    template <typename Callable, typename... Arguments>
    PeriodicFunction(Callable&& callable, Arguments&&... arguments)
    :   m_function(std::bind(
            std::move(callable),
            std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...)),
        m_period(period_type::zero())
    {}

    public:
    PeriodicFunction(const PeriodicFunction&) = delete;
    PeriodicFunction& operator = (const PeriodicFunction&) = delete;

    /// Calls stop.
    ~PeriodicFunction() { stop(); }

    // Start/Stop
    // ==========

    /// True, if an invocation thread is active.
    bool active() const noexcept { return m_thread.joinable(); }

    /// Start an invocation thread and repeatedly invoke the function (in the given period)
    /// after the given delay.
    /// - If a previous invocation thread is active, no invocation of the function
    ///   takes place.
    /// - After the first invocation of the function (at least one is done):
    ///   - If the period is or has become zero (due to a call to stop) the
    ///     invocation thread stops without any further invocation of the function.
    ///   - As long as an invocation of the function has not finished, the next
    ///     possible invocation is delayed by the given period.
    /// \EXCEPTION All exceptions stop the invocation thread and the exception of the
    ///            last invocation is avaliable through a call to rethorow_exception.
    /// \RETURN    True if no previous call to start is active, otherwise false.
    /// \NOTE      The period is not an exact value (due to interleaving calls between
    ///            each invocation of the function).
    public:
    template <
        typename Period, typename  PeriodRatio,
        typename Delay, typename DelayRatio>
    bool start(
        const std::chrono::duration<Period, PeriodRatio>& period,
        const std::chrono::duration<Delay, DelayRatio>& delay) noexcept;

    /// Start an invocation thread and repeatedly invoke the function without delay.
    template <typename Period, typename PeriodRatio>
    bool start(const std::chrono::duration<Period, PeriodRatio>& period) noexcept {
        return start(period, std::chrono::duration<Period, PeriodRatio>::zero());
    }

    /// Set the period of invocations to zero.
    /// If an invocation thread is active, stop invocations of the function
    /// and wait until the thread has finished.
    /// \SEE std::thread::join
    void stop() {
        m_period = period_type::zero();
        if(active()) m_thread.join();
    }

    // Period
    // ======

    public:
    const period_type& period() const noexcept { return m_period; }

    // Exception
    // =========

    public:
    /// True if an exception occured in the last invocation thread.
    bool exception() const { return bool(m_exception); }
    /// Throw the exception of the last invocation thread, if availabe.
    void rethrow_exception() const {
        if(exception())
            std::rethrow_exception(m_exception);
    }

    // Utility [invoke_synchron]
    // =========================

    private:
    void invoke_synchron() {
        invoke_synchron(std::is_same<value_type, void>());
    }
    // not void
    void invoke_synchron(std::false_type) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->transfer(m_function());
    }
    // void
    void invoke_synchron(std::true_type) {
        m_function();
    }

    // Utility [invoke_asynchron]
    // ==========================

    private:
    void invoke_asynchron() {
        m_future = std::async(std::launch::async, m_function);
    }

    // Utility [transfer_asynchron]
    // ============================

    private:
    void transfer_asynchron() {
        transfer_asynchron(std::is_same<value_type, void>());
    }
    // not void
    void transfer_asynchron(std::false_type) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->transfer(m_future.get());
    }
    // void
    void transfer_asynchron(std::true_type) {
        m_future.get();
    }

    private:
    function_type m_function;
    period_type m_period;
    std::thread m_thread;
    future_type m_future;
    std::exception_ptr m_exception;
};

// Start/Stop
// ==========

template <typename Value, typename Derived>
template <
    typename Period, typename  PeriodRatio,
    typename Delay, typename DelayRatio>
bool PeriodicFunction<Value, Derived>::start(
    const std::chrono::duration<Period, PeriodRatio>& period,
    const std::chrono::duration<Delay, DelayRatio>& delay) noexcept
{
    if(active()) return false;
    try {
        m_exception = std::exception_ptr();
        m_period = std::chrono::duration_cast<period_type>(period);
        m_thread = std::thread([this, delay]() {
            try {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
                if(this->m_period == period_type::zero()) this->invoke_synchron();
                else {
                    this->invoke_asynchron();
                    while(true) {
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(this->m_period);
                        if(this->m_period != period_type::zero()) {
                            if(this->m_future.wait_for(period_type::zero()) == std::future_status::ready) {
                                this->transfer_asynchron();
                                this->invoke_asynchron();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            this->m_future.wait();
                            this->transfer_asynchron();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(...) {
                this->m_exception = std::current_exception();
            }
        });
    }
    catch(...) {
        this->m_exception = std::current_exception();
    }
    return true;
}

} // namespace Detail


// PeriodicFunction
// =============================================================================

template <typename Value>
class PeriodicFunction : public Detail::PeriodicFunction<Value, PeriodicFunction<Value>>
{
    // Types
    // =====

    private:
    typedef Detail::PeriodicFunction<Value, PeriodicFunction<Value>> Base;
    friend Base;

    public:
    typedef typename Base::period_type period_type;
    typedef typename Base::value_type value_type;
    typedef std::list<value_type> result_type;

    private:
    typedef std::mutex mutex;

    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    template <typename Callable, typename... Arguments>
    PeriodicFunction(Callable&& callable, Arguments&&... arguments)
    :   Base(callable, std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...)
    {}

    // Result
    // ======

    /// True, if the internal result buffer is empty.
    bool empty() const { return m_result.empty(); }

    /// Return the current result of invocations of the function and clear
    /// the result buffer.
    /// \NOTE If the invoking thread is still running, new results
    ///       might become available.
    result_type result() {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_result_mutex);
        return std::move(m_result);
    }

    // Utility
    // =======

    private:
    void transfer(value_type&& result) {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_result_mutex);
        m_result.push_back(result);
    }

    private:
    mutex m_result_mutex;
    result_type m_result;
};



// PeriodicFunction<void>
// ======================

template <>
class PeriodicFunction<void> : public Detail::PeriodicFunction<void, PeriodicFunction<void>>
{
    // Types
    // =====

    private:
    typedef Detail::PeriodicFunction<void, PeriodicFunction<void>> Base;
    friend Base;

    public:
    typedef typename Base::period_type period_type;
    typedef typename Base::value_type value_type;


    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    template <typename Callable, typename... Arguments>
    PeriodicFunction(Callable&& callable, Arguments&&... arguments)
    :   Base(callable, std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...)
    {}
};


// Test
// ====

#define TEST_OUTPUT 0

class Exception : public std::runtime_error
{
    public:
    Exception() noexcept
    :   std::runtime_error("Test")
    {}
};

const unsigned f_limit = 10;
std::atomic<unsigned> f_count;
char f() {
    ++f_count;
    return '.';
}

const unsigned g_limit = 3;
std::atomic<unsigned> g_count;
void g() {
    if(++g_count == g_limit) throw Exception();
}


int main()
{
    try {
        using std::chrono::milliseconds;
        // With Return Type
        {
            PeriodicFunction<char> invoke(f);
            #if(TEST_OUTPUT)
            std::ostream& stream = std::cout;
            #else
            std::ostream null(0);
            std::ostream& stream = null;
            #endif
            invoke.start(milliseconds(10));
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < f_limit; ++i) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(100));
                if(i == f_count - 1) invoke.stop();
                auto result = invoke.result();
                for(const auto& r : result)
                    stream << r;
                stream << '\n';
            }
        }
        // Void
        {
            PeriodicFunction<void> invoke(g);
            invoke.start(milliseconds(10), milliseconds(100));
            // A thread shall throw an exception before stopping
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(200));
            invoke.stop();
            try { invoke.rethrow_exception(); }
            catch(Exception) { return 0; }
        }
    }
    catch(...) {}
    return -1;
}
```

**Fixes:**

The stop function will fail if called from the same thread, hence I changed it to:

```
void stop() {
    m_period = period_type::zero();
    if(is_active() && std::this_thread::get_id() != m_thread.get_id())
        m_thread.join();
}
```

The `PeriodicFunction::result()` does not clear the internal state of the result container after the move:

```
result_type result() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_result_mutex);
    result_type result(std::move(m_result));
    m_result.clear();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `typedef std::mutex mutex;`? Also you can't return -1 from `main`.

Comment: @no1 You can, in fact, return `-1` from `main`. It has the effect of calling `std::exit` with an argument of `-1`, which, according to [support.start.term], has implementation-defined behavior. On POSIX systems, this is equivalent to returning 255.

Comment: @ruds I said that because he likely expected a `$?` = `-1`, but that won't happen since the shell uses an 8 bit unsigned int (char o whatever) for the return type.
Also, in case of failure, you should return a positive value different from zero.

Comment: The EXIT_FAILURE macro, defined in <cstdlib>, is probably a good default if you don't intend to return specific statuses to the shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, the code already seems really good. Therefore, I have nothing more than a few notes:

- It is more of a matter of taste, but I would use some [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead of the old `typedef`. The type aliases can be templated (contrary to `typedef`) and provide a syntax that is close to variable assignements (`auto a = 89;`) and namespace aliases (`namespace foobar = foo::bar;`). That means that you can write code which looks more consistent:

  ```
  using period_type = std::chrono::milliseconds;
  using value_type = Value;

  using function_type = std::function<Value ()>;
  using future_type = std::future<Value>;
  ```
- C++ has special syntax to import type names from a base class without having to use a full `typedef` or type alias, you can use it to reduce the amount of code and make explicit your intent in `PeriodicFunction`:

  ```
  using typename Base::period_type;
  using typename Base::value_type;
  ```
- `typedef std::mutex mutex;` seems useless and potentially confusing. I would drop the `typedef` and use `std::mutex` everywhere instead. It shouldn't hinder readability.
- In [their answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46815/15094) to your previous question, @ruds said that `Timer::m_results` should not be `mutable`, which is right, but I see no harm in having the corresponding `std::mutex` be `mutable`. It does not seem to be currently useful though.
- Really no more than a tidbit, but namespaces are generally lowercase. Consider replacing `Detail` by `detail`.
- Functions that return a `bool` tend to be more understandable when their name is more than just a name. For example, `bool exception() {}` makes me think that the function returns an `std::exception` or a derived class (which would be odd). Consider renaming it `exception_occured` instead. Also, consider renaming `active` to `is_active`.

  Unfortunately, the standard library containers have a function `empty` while `is_empty` would have been a better name ("empty" somehow means "empty that container" to me); I understand that you keep this particular name for consistency.

Discussing what can be improved is good, but I also want to put a note about what you did right: tag dispatching with `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` is great. It helps to write simple and readable code and to avoid some `std::enable_if` and template boilerplate. You also correctly implemented perfect forwarding and used proper scoped locks. Kudos for that :)